Implementation of torch.nn.Conv1d in C++
I'm looking for comprehend explanation or implementation of PyTorch.Conv1d layer in C++.
Let's define conv1d layer as:
BATCH_SIZE = 20
INPUT_SIZE = 160
OUTPUT_SIZE = 64
KERNEL_SIZE = int(self.INPUT_SIZE / self.BATCH_SIZE) # 8
l = torch.nn.Conv1d(BATCH_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE,
                             kernel_size=KERNEL_SIZE,
                             bias=False, dtype=torch.float64))
# and the input
inp = some_lin_x_160.view(BATCH_SIZE, -1)
l(inp)

Although all sources I found specify the output size like: (inp_channels - kernel_size + 1)/stride I'm not entirely clear how pytorch handles arbitrary(defined by client code) out_channels.
This is the very naive implementation of the layer based on Eigen library, and I'm pretty sure it's wrong.
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 160> Input_t;
typedef Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<64, 20, 8>> Conv1d_t;
Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 64> conv1d(
    const Input_t& raw_input,
    const Conv1d_t& weights) noexcept {

    auto input = Eigen::Matrix<T, 20, 8>(raw_input.data());
    auto output = Eigen::Matrix<double, 64, 1>();
    output.setZero();

    for (int out_ch = 0; out_ch < 64; out_ch++) {
        for (int bs = 0; bs < 20; bs++)
            for (int k=0; k<8; k++)
                output(out_ch, 0) += input(bs, k) * weights(out_ch, bs, k);
    }
    return output.transpose();
}

I'm really appreciate for the any help with the question.

What do you mean by arbitrary out_channels? out_channels is an explicitly set fixed parameter

@Karl thank you for the question, I clarified the post. So, it means that it does not (completely or not) depend only on inp_channels, kernel_size, stride.

I still don't understand your question. A 1d convolution has a weight of shape (out_channels, in_channels, kernel_size). It takes an input of shape (bs, in_channels, d_in) and produces an output of shape (bs, out_channels, d_out) where d_out = floor(((d_in + 2*padding - dilation * (kernel_size - 1) - 1)/stride) + 1). The number of out_channels defines the shape of the weight matrix which defines the shape out the output.

Thanks to @Kari for clarifying in the comments.
So in this particular case there was a problem with the default StorageOptions in Eigen, which is column major by default. This is fixed version of implementation sketch:
constexpr static int input_channels = 160;
constexpr static int output_channels = 64;
constexpr static int batch_number = 20;
constexpr static int kernel_size = ...;

typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, input_channels> Input_t;
typedef Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<output_channels, batch_number, kernel_size>> Conv1d_t;
auto conv1d(
    const Input_t& raw_input,
    const Conv1d_t& weights) noexcept {

    constexpr auto seq = input_channels/batch_number - kernel_size + 1;
    constexpr auto batch_size = input_channels / batch_number;
    auto input = mapInto<batch_number, batch_size, Eigen::RowMajor>(raw_input);
    auto output = Eigen::Matrix<double, output_channels, 1>();
    output.setZero();

    for (int out_ch = 0; out_ch < output_channels; out_ch++)
        for (int s = 0; s<seq; s++)
            for (int bs = 0; bs < batch_number; bs++)
                for (int k=0; k<kernel_size; k++)
                    output(out_ch, s) += input(bs, k + s) * weights(out_ch, bs, k);

    return output.transpose();
}

